# Edit Multiple Excel Workbooks

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have 50 Excel workbooks (Excel 2007) that were sent out to staff. The problem is that I forgot to "unlock" some cells on all of them which makes them uneditable while the worksheet is protected. I cannot ask staff to unlock the cells for reasons beyond the scope of this question.

All workbooks have now been emailed back to me.

How can I  - Unprotect each sheet(which is password protected) and unlock the required cells without having to perform this 50 times? Is there a way to do it without writing VBA?

MC

Comment: I believe it's possible to use Visual Studio with office interop to do this. Take a look here and see if it helps any: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/af1c41xy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: You will need to write some code to do this - VBA is one option.

Comment: If the location is the same, or can be determined with rules, thenis pretty simple to loop through a group of workbooks with vba or vbscript and update them

Comment: @brettdj. That seems an appropriate methodology to solve my problem.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The consensus seems to be that the answers are "Use VBA" and "No".